# can i use this to create Document sets dynamically in a doc lib - SharePoint Online

Tags: client-object-model, document-set

I would like to create a document set dynamically using a filed from an excel sheet.
Can I use Client side (CSOM) and powershell for this. 
 Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

### How to create a Document Set using SharePoint CSOM in PowerShell

Use [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentSet.DocumentSet.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj675436%28v=office.12%29.aspx) method to create a `DocumentSet` object:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentManagement")

Function Get-SPOCredentials([string]$UserName,[string]$Password)
{
    $SecurePassword = $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    return New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $SecurePassword)
}

Function Create-DocumentSet([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext]$Context, [String]$ListTitle,[String]$DocSetName) {
    $list = $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($listTitle)

    $docSetContentType = $Context.Site.RootWeb.ContentTypes.GetById("0x0120D520")
    $Context.Load($docSetContentType)
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()

    $result = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.DocumentSet.DocumentSet]::Create($Context, $list.RootFolder, $DocSetName, $docSetContentType.Id);
    $Context.ExecuteQuery()

    return $result.Value 
}
```

Usage

```
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Url)
$context.Credentials = Get-SPOCredentials -UserName $UserName -Password $Password
$docSetUrl = Create-DocumentSet -Context $context -ListTitle "Documents" -DocSetName "Orders"
$context.Dispose()
```